# pytest AttributeError: "function object has no attribute" when referencing fixture in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have a model and a controller I'm trying to test:

```
class Model:

    def __init__(self):
        self.display = ""

    def set_display(self, display):
        self.display = display

import pytest
from model import Model
from controller import Controller

@pytest.fixture
def model():
    return Model()

@pytest.fixture
def controller(model):
    return Controller(model)

def test_clear_button(controller):
    controller.button_pressed("4")
    controller.button_pressed("2")
    controller.button_pressed("C")
    assert model.display == "0"
```

E       AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'display'

Above is the errors/failures I get every time I run the test.

```
class Controller:

    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model

    def button_pressed(self, button_label):
        pass
```

Comment: Shouldn't `model` be `model()`?

Comment: Please try to fix the formatting of the example, and reduce it down. If the problem is with a test, we only need that one test. And if the problem is with pressing a button, we don't need a dozen buttons when one will do for the purposes of this question.

Comment: where @RandomDavis it is class so why ()?

Comment: I meant in lines like `assert model.display == "0"`, you're referring to the `model` method, not the `Model()` class. You probably should try using `model()` instead, since that actually returns an instance of the `Model` class.

Comment: @RandomDavis now it gives  > controller_test.py:23: AssertionError with more scarier errors

Comment: @AnkitDwivedi that's not enough info. Also you should put all code and outputs in your original post, not in comments.

Comment: @AnkitDwivedi The fact that you error changed when you made it be `model().display` implies that you fixed that error and that the remaining problems are with the code you're testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture), by doing:

```
@pytest.fixture
def model():
    return Model()
```

and then:

```
@pytest.fixture
def controller(model):
    return Controller(model)
```

you define a fixture called `controller` that references another fixture called `model` to define the `model` on that instance of the `Controller` class. Therefore, it seems that you're not referencing `model` correctly:

```
def test_clear_button(controller):
    controller.button_pressed("4")
    controller.button_pressed("2")
    controller.button_pressed("C")
    assert controller.model.display == "0"
```

or, alternatively:

```
def test_clear_button(controller, model):
    controller.button_pressed("4")
    controller.button_pressed("2")
    controller.button_pressed("C")
    assert model.display == "0"
```

Comment: If I am not wrong you mean I should change to this assert model().display == "0"
but this also throws error

Comment: @AnkitDwivedi Correct. And I expect it would because you're testing code. This will resolve the error you posted about but that doesn't mean your code will magically run as you expect when you fix it. There could be other errors that were masked by this one

Comment: RemovedInPytest4Warning: Fixture "model" called directl                                                                                                    y. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly, are created automatically when                                                                                                     test functions request them as parameters. See https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest                                                                                                    /fixture.html for more information.
any idea what this means?

Comment: thank you so much @Woody1193 that was the issue and my apologies for the bad explanation!

Comment: @AnkitDwivedi No worries. Glad I could be of help

Comment: I am not following what you did differently and why this works

Comment: @Gulzar The primary issue was that he wasn't accessing the `model` variable properly. If you define `test_clear_button` to take `model` then you can access it directly, which the OP didn't do. If you don't then you have to access `model` by doing `controller.model`, which the OP also didn't do.